# How to set permament TCP Windows Size in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, tcp, performance-tuning

I'm checking real throughput of my network using iperf/jperf. Test with speedtest.net shows 25/10 - but jperf shows only 5. So I change in jperf the TCP Window Size into 256K - and now jperf shows 17Mbit - i think it's quite ok, but how to set it permamently? If I restart jperf - and no change of TCP Window - it is again 5Mbit.

So dig the internet and found http://www.speedguide.net/articles/windows-2kxp-registry-tweaks-157 -> I set the GlobalTCPWindows and many more. Than restart the computer, and... nothing happens. jperf shows still 5 until I change the jperf parameter into 256K....

Any ideas?

Current registry settings:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters]

"TcpWindowSize"=dword:0007d780
"GlobalMaxTcpWindowSize"=dword:0007d780
"Tcp1323Opts"=dword:00000001
"EnablePMTUDiscovery"=dword:00000001
"EnablePMTUBHDetect"=dword:00000000
"TcpMaxDupAcks"=dword:00000002
"SackOpts"=dword:00000001
"DefaultTTL"=dword:00000040
"DisableTaskOffload"=dword:00000000
"MaxUserPort"=dword:0000fffe
"TcpTimedWaitDelay"=dword:0000001e


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\AFD\Parameters]
"FastSendDatagramThreshold"=dword:000005dc
"FastCopyReceiveThreshold"=dword:000005dc
"DefaultSendWindow"=dword:00002000
```

I don't know if I change more settings - ask me about current status of any setting

Unfortunately I have to low reputation to add images, so I have to put it on my web:

http://www.brzezina.pl/tcp.html

Comment: **What enteries did you edit exactly.**

Comment: Many ;D - I edit question and show Current settings

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that speedtest.net can aggregate multiple connections to send data whereas iperf will use one connection. The maximum throughput of a single connection depends on:

- Bandwidth
- Send window (buffer size)
- Receive window (buffer size)
- Latency
- Network congestion

It sounds like you're talking about upload or send performance. In that case, you want to increase the default send window size. You can do that by editing the registry key:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\AFD\Parameters\DefaultSendWindow`

And setting it an 256k or whatever is appropriate for your [Bandwidth Delay Product](http://www.speedguide.net/faq_in_q.php?qid=185).

There's a good paper discussing performance tuning for XP/2003 [here](http://www.innominate.com/data/downloads/manuals/appnot_perf_tuning.pdf).

Comment: Ok, I understand, that speedtest.net aggregates multiple connections, but i focus on iperf. On one connection I can get 17Mbit when I set TCP Window Size. So I want to set TCP Windows Size outside the iperf/jperf and run it and without changing the setting i want to get the 17Mbit result